# Delete certain length of substring

Tags: bash

A call of `svn status` gives me a list of files that are different than in the svn image.

```
D       subs/abc/deleted_sub.f90
M       subs/abc/modified_sub.f90
M       subs/abc/Makefile.Routinen
```

I need a string `compile_string` to `gmake $compile_string`.

What I do not want in my string are files declared `D` for `deleted` and `Makefile.Routinen` files.

I do also not want to work with temporary files (I have a working script but using temporary files is not desirable).

So I read my svn status into a string:

```
comp_files=$(svn status)
```

So I get a long string `D subs/abc/deleted_sub.f90 M subs/abc/modified_sub.f90 M subs/abc/Makefile.Routinen`.

How can I now delete the next filepath after a 'D' or if its a Makefile.Routinen file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
comp_files=$(svn status | grep -E -v '^D|Makefile.Routinen')
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is a good fit when working with columns

```
comp_files=$(svn status | awk '$1 != "D" && $2 !~ /Makefile\.Routinen/{print $2}')
```

- `$1 != "D"` first column shouldn't match literal string `D`
- `$2 !~ /Makefile\.Routinen/` second column shouldn't contain the string `Makefile.Routinen`
- `{print $2}` if both conditions satisfy, print second column

If entire line content is needed instead of second column alone,

```
comp_files=$(svn status | awk '$1 != "D" && $2 !~ /Makefile\.Routinen/')
```